# Python async download files: Async Await vs Concurrent Futures

Tags: python, asynchronous

I need to download a large number of files and save them to my local machine. Given the introduction of Async Await in python is it best to use this method, or use continue to use Concurrent.Futures with something like:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the url and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

Comment: What are the pros and cons of using Async Await vs Concurrent Futures. Both solve this problem

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html): "The concurrent.futures module provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables."